# Parse data between the brackets from a string - Java

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to parse data from the `[]` in a `String` in java

```
String text = "some text [Karan] some text";
```

> I want to the computer to read `Karan` present inside the brackets

I have tried `String.split()` method but it packs it into an array which I don't want.

Is there any way to do this. Thank you

Comment: Someone will downvote you because you didn't try anything to ask for help. You asked someone to do it for you. SO rules say to try something and then ask for help. By the way, a little search will get you the answer.

Comment: those are called brackets, not parens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex like this:

```
String text = "some text [Karan] some [test2] text [test3] [test4] 22[test5]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])");
//or use this regex,it works well too
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)[^\\[\\]]*(?=\\])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

and the result is `Karan`,`test2`,`test3`,`test4`,`test5`.
Regex is useful for processing text.This improved version of regular is using "Positive and Negative Lookbehind".Thanks for Matthieu's suggestions.

Comment: The only valid answer. Though you might want to check *look-aheads* to exclude the brackets themselves from the groups.

Comment: Yes,because the bracket is only the keyword to distinguish what in it and out.

Comment: I mean use "positive and negative look behind". You can use `(?<=\[).*(?=\])` to capture *only* what is between brackets, without capturing the brackets themselves. See https://regex101.com/ to test, and the awesome https://www.regular-expressions.info/ for all about regex.

Comment: Even better, to separate all groups: `(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*(?=\])`

Comment: Your suggestion is great.And I have tried two solutions.For the first regex (?<=\[).*(?=\]) it has a little short,it will match the text like "Karan] some [word2".So compensate for it should be (?<=\[).*?(?=\]),using the not greedy pattern.And the second regex is another good way to match the text.I will edit my answer later with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [`String.substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method in combination with [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)).

Here is a short description of how you would extract text between brackets `[]` using these two methods:

1. Get the index of the first bracket `[` character using `String.indexOf` method. (let's call this value `start`)
2. Get the index of the second bracket `]` character using `String.indexOf` method (let's call this value `end`)
3. Call `.substring` on the string you are extracting information from with

   ```
   text.substring(start+1, end)
   ```

Note how the first index `start+1` is *inclusive* and `end` is *exclusive*.

Comment: ... or better: use regular expression splitting.

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, I agree. I just wanted to share a simpler approach given that the question is from a novice programmer. Just didn't want to overload with him regex :)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this then:

```
String text = "some text [Karen] some text";
text = text.substring(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.indexOf("]"));
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: `some [text] and [other] text` => `text] and [other`. Really?

Comment: You are right, my post does not work with more brackets and the other solution is much better, but the result with your example would still be “text”. The second one is just missing.

Comment: That's why regexp is the way to go.